How to find the exact optimal bound
Is there any way to fix or revise this code to find the EXACT optimal bound, and could anyone help find the EXACT optimal bound? Thanks.
constructM[x_, y_, z_] := Module[{M},
  M = Outer[Times, x, x] + Outer[Times, y, y] + Outer[Times, z, z];
  M
]

submatrix[M_, i_, j_] := Module[{indices},
  indices = Complement[Range[Length[M]], {i + 1, j + 1}];
  M[[indices, indices]]
]

minEigenvalue[M_] := Min[Eigenvalues[M]]

objective[vars_] := Module[{x, y, z, M, minEigenvalues},
  x = Normalize[vars[[1 ;; 5]]];
  y = Normalize[vars[[6 ;; 10]]];
  z = Normalize[vars[[11 ;; 15]]];
  
  M = constructM[x, y, z];
  
  minEigenvalues = {};
  Do[
    AppendTo[minEigenvalues, minEigenvalue[submatrix[M, i, j]]],
    {i, 0, 4}, {j, i + 1, 4}
  ];
  
  -Min[minEigenvalues]
]

runMultipleOptimizations[numTrials_] := Module[{optimalBounds, optimalVectors, result, initialGuess, bestBound, bestVectors},
  optimalBounds = {};
  optimalVectors = {};
  
  Do[
    initialGuess = RandomReal[1, 15];
    result = NMinimize[objective[initialGuess], initialGuess, 
      Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"];
    
    If[result[[1]] < Infinity,
      AppendTo[optimalBounds, -result[[1]]];
      AppendTo[optimalVectors, Normalize[result[[2]]]];
    ];
  , {numTrials}];
  
  bestBound = Max[optimalBounds];
  bestVectors = optimalVectors[[First[Ordering[optimalBounds, -1]]]];
  
  {bestBound, bestVectors}
]

numTrials = 10^4;
{bestBound, {xBest, yBest, zBest}} = runMultipleOptimizations[numTrials];

Print["Optimal upper bound after ", numTrials, " trials: ", bestBound];
Print["Optimal vector x: ", xBest];
Print["Optimal vector y: ", yBest];
Print["Optimal vector z: ", zBest];



(The above code defines a function to generate random unit vectors in R^5 and Function to delete ith and jth rows and columns from a matrix, ...)

If I scrape-n-paste your code into Mathematica and run it then all it displays is Eigenvalues[Real[]] Can you do exactly what I did and verify that? And then can you modify your code so that it displays what I assume is supposed to be a non-exact optimal bound and show the result that you got from your example code? Thanks

@Bill Did you see that the question is about the EXACT bound? What functions in Mathematica would you use to effectively find the EXACT bound? Thanks.

Yes I saw your question is about the EXACT bound. So I scrape-n-pasted your code in to MMA, expecting to get something like 3.1 or something similar when you knew it was not EXACTLY 3.1, and I thought when I could see the 3.1 I might be able to help, but I got nothing that seemed like a bound. I see you edited your code an hour ago so again I scrape-n-paste and run your code and now I get findMinimalUpperBound[1000] as output. So right after subMatrices=Table[deleteRowsCols[M,{i,j}],{i,1,5},{j,i+1,5}]; I insert Print[subMatrices]; I think that shows a problem. Do you agree?

@Bill  The code has been updated. Could you revise it to find the exact optimal upper bound? Thanks.

I would be very happy if you could explain, in more detail, "bound" of what? and "optimal" in which sense?

@A.Kato The "bound" refers to the upper bound for the "minEigenvalue"; and the "optimal" upper bound means the smallest upper bound. Best regards.

Thank you. What you want is $\max_{x,y,z\in S^{5}} (\min_{i<j} f(x,y,z,i,j))$, where $f(x,y,z,i,j)$ is the smallest eigenvalue of $3\times 3$ matrix submatrix[M, i, j] and M=constructM[x,y,z]. Am I correct?

Typo in my previous comment. $S^5$ should be $S^4$ (unit sphere in $R^5$).

@A.Kato  Yes, that is correct. Best regards.

Sorry but I don't have enough time now. I think the extremal case of $x=(1,0,0,0,0)$, $y=(0,1,0,0,0)$, $z=(0,0,1,0,0)$ is important. By the way, you said $\max_{x,y,z\in S^{4}}(\min_{i<j}(x,y,z,i,j))$ is what you want. Really? Not $\max_{x,y,z\in S^{4}}(\max_{i<j}(x,y,z,i,j))$?

@A.Kato It is the maximal minimum.

@A.Kato Do you have any insights on how to find the answer? Thanks.

Sorry. No insights yet.

@Venus, please do not make trivial tags edits every day to bump your post. If you want it to get more attention, please start a bounty.

@Domen, they do not have enough reputation to start a bounty

Could anyone find a minimum that is not less than 0.15? Thanks.
